# Target jsp form in casperjs

Tags: web-scraping, phantomjs, web-crawler, casperjs

Casperjs quickstart google search code:

```
this.fill('form[action="/search"]', { q: 'google search' }, true);
```

---

**How can I target this form in casperjs?**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [fillSelectors()](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#fillselectors) function:

```
this.fillSelectors('form#frm_one', {q: 'google search'}, true);
```